# How to add logging to a function in Bash which is also expected to return a value?

Tags: bash, shell, logging, sh

In bash we return values by echo, printf or similar, right?

Then how do you add logging to a function if everything printed will be mixed in the returned value? The following example better explains what I'm trying to accomplish

**Sample code**

```
function main() {
    local variable=$(nested)
    echo "Variable value is: $variable"
}

function nested() {
    printf "Value"
    logger
}

function logger() {
    printf "Random Log\n"
}

main
```

**Expected output**

```
Randomg Log
Variable value is: Value
```

**Actual output**

```
Variable value is: ValueRandomg Log
```

Comment: Logs usually go to the standard error. Try `function logger() { ... } >&2`

Comment: @oguzismail even if they are INFO? Because if someone does 2> /dev/null it won't print anything

Comment: Then clearly they don't want informational messages to be displayed.

Comment: Yes that's a common consequence of throwing stderr away. You can use a different file descriptor if you want the user to be able to dump stderr but still see logs, but then you're responsible for pointing it to the right place (terminal, file, etc). The important thing is you have to write somewhere other than stdout because `var=$( cmd )` is soaking up all the stdout to store it in var.

Comment: Yes, even if it is INFO, because you can only use stdout to return a value. One workaround (only mentioning, I still prefer to use stderr) could be that you encode the error in the result, and then interpret it outside the function. If you return a string like `{ "ret": "value", "err": "random log" }`, and pass it through `jq` after the call, you can have both (but delay the error message!). I still wouldn't go there though. Just use stderr for all log messages.

Comment: I agree, passing it to stderr seems to be the way

Comment: Writing to standard output is not the only way for a function to return non-trivial values.  In fact, there are multiple problems with doing that.  Your question illustrates one of them.  Other problems include poor performance, mangling of string terminations, and difficulty in returning lists or multiple values.  See [BashFAQ/084 (How do I return a string \(or large number, or negative number\) from a function? "return" only lets me give a number from 0 to 255.)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/084) for alternatives.

Comment: @pjh Thank you so much for the input, those are great ideas!